# Serialization and Deserialization of a Tree to/from String in Java

Tags: java, string, serialization, tree, deserialization

I have a Tree which has multiple children. I have to serialize the tree to a string and deserialize it back from a string to a Tree. I am able to serialize the Tree to a string. I am using the following format: 
(-- Begin children for an Node
)-- End children for a Node
, -- Delimiter for children for a Node

Ex: 1(11(111(1111),112),12(121,122,123),13(131))

However I am not able to deserialize the above string to a Tree in Java. Please help. Some Example code would help.

I am open to serializing the String to another format too as long as I am able to deserialize it.

Comment: In the above example, the Tree structure is as follows:

Tree Root = 1
1's children = 11,12,13
11's children = 111,112
12's children = 121, 122, 123
13's child = 131
111's child = 1111

Comment: Sorry. Let me clarify. When I say, I am open to another format, I meant another format for the string. I have to serialize the Tree to a String.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to other formats (as stated) and use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) it'll likely serialise/deserialise to XML without any further work on your part. You can further customise the serialisation as required.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Jackon and serialize to JSon?